# Having trouble downloading the game

Tags: unity-web-player, yandere-simulator

Whenever I download Yandere simulator, it either tries to open it with Windows Media Center or Unity Player. I am pretty sure I remember making files that are similar open the same programme by accident.... I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me?[image: Options]

Answer (score 4):

The file type that is downloaded is a RAR file, similar to a zip file. You will need either [winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) or [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract it. Then, there will most likely be an exe inside that you can run and will run the game.

Comment: If it worked for you, consider marking this as the correct answer (the little white checkmark below the downvote button).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation? lol

Comment: The checkmark below the down arrow. You can accept a question at any amount of reputation.